# For a sequence of positive terms $(a_n)$, such that $a^{2}_{n+1}=a_n+2$ and $(a_n)\rightarrow a$ prove that $a=2$. Prove that $(a_n)$ is monotonic.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For a sequence of positive terms $(a_n)$, such that$a^{2}_{n+1}=a_n+2$ and $(a_n)\rightarrow a$ prove that $a=2$. Prove that $(a_n)$ is monotonic.

Use the sum rule, product rule, and closed interval property.

---

I don't really know where to get started with this problem.

I started by considering: $a^{2}_{n+2}-a^{2}_{n+1}=a_{n+1}+2-(a_{n}+2)\Rightarrow(a_{n+2}-a_{n+1})(a_{n+2}+a_{n+1})=a_{n+1}-a_n$. From this we can say that $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}$ has the same sign as $a_{n+1}-a_n$ because $(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive terms so $a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}$ is always positive.

I believe this is sufficient to prove that $(a_n)$ is a monotonic sequence. I still can't really figure out where to get started with proving $a=2$.

I tried setting $0\leq a_n\leq a_n+2$ but can't see how this inequality would lead me to the answer. The sum rule gives $(a_n-a)+2\rightarrow2$, but I can't see how to take it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If $a_n\to a$, then $a^2=a+2$. I let you find $a$. For the monotonicity, induction works well.

Comment: Does my argument not prove monotonicity?

Comment: $a_n\leq a_{n+1}^2$ doesn't imply that $a_n\leq a_{n+1}$.

Comment: But I showed $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}$ has the same sign as $a_{n+1}-a_n$.

Comment: @shredalert Yes, your proof of monotonicity is correct. But you need to also prove that the sequence is bounded before concluding that it converges.

Comment: @dxiv Could you please specify which sequence are you referring to?

Comment: @shredalert The sequence $(a_n)$ of course.

Comment: @dxiv $(a_n)\rightarrow a$ [This is provided in the question]. Is this not enough to say $(a_n)$ is bounded?

Comment: @shredalert It depends on the definitions and notations that you work with whether that includes the case $a=\infty$ or not. If $a$ is finite then, yes, the sequence must be bounded. Otherwise, you can exclude the case $a=\infty$ by proving that the sequence is in fact bounded, regardless of what the first term $a_1 \ge 0$ is.

Answer (score 0):

From $a^{2}_{n+1}=a_n+2$ and $a_n \to a$ we get

$a^2=a+2$. This equation has the solutions $a=2$ and $a=-1$. Since all $a_n >0$, we get $a \ge 0$ , hence $a=2$.

Prove $a_{n+1} \le a_n$ by induction.

Comment: Why $a_{n+1}\le a_n$? Take $a_1=1$ then $a_2=\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @Arnaldo I was wondering along the same lines. I don't think there is sufficient information to show it is monotonic increasing or decreasing, just monotonic.

Comment: Ooops, you are right

Comment: @shredalert: you are right. You just can prove that $a_n$ is monotonic.

Answer (score 0):

Let  $a_n\rightarrow a$ then $a_{n+1}\rightarrow a$
Now $a^2_{n+1}=a_n +2$ As $n\rightarrow \infty$ the expression takes the form $a^2=a+2$. Solve this quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0):

For the  monotonicity, show that: $a_n <2 $ implies $\sqrt {a_n+2}>a_n $ , $a_n >2 $ implies $\sqrt {a_n+2}<a_n $ and naturally $a_n=2$ implies $a_{n+1}=2$. That is, the sequence is monotonic for any choice of $a_1$.